# Kubernetes does not recognize modification of service

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

How can I force Kubernetes to "recognize" the modification of a service?

I eventually change the type/spec of an service from

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-a
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: service-a-pods
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
```

to

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-a
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: service-b.namespace-b.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
```

This works fine, but when I revert the change in Kubernetes, the `service-a` still keeps forwarding to the `service-b` in `namespace-b`. Even hard deleting and recreating `service-a` does not help.

It seems like the CoreDNS is not updated or something like this. The only work-around I found, is to recreate `service-b` in `namespace-b`. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: In general, it should not be occurring as you're changing your configurations and reapplying them, but at times when using coreDNS, these records might not be removed properly from cache resulting in such issues. This can be resolved by flushing the coreDNS records or by restarting coreDNS pods.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni is this a known bug in CoreDNS? Unfortunately I do not have permissions to do anything with CodeDNS.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a bug or intended behavior as this happened in my case only when I was changing the configs very frequently and regarding the other point you need not do any changes to coreDNS you just need to restart the pods present in coreDNS namespace or the pods starting with name coreDNS this will help you easily solve your issue instead of recreating or redeploying pods or service.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the cache of DNS records maintained by coredns in your k8s cluster. You can reduce the following ttl value to zero if you need the immediate effect of your service resource changes:

Run following to edit the Corefile (coredns configuration file):

```
kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
```

then update the TTL under `kubernetes` plugin:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 0 # <-- set this ttl value to zero
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
```

Note: This might have a performance impact on DNS resolutions in your cluster. You can reduce it to an appropriate value as well.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not to be the reason for my issue. My TTL is the default of 5s. But the DNS is not updated at all - or at least not for > 15 min